# formatting data in Freemarketnet

Tags: model-view-controller, freemarker

Am using freemarketnet to replace macros with proper content. for that am sending json object from mvc controller to view. In view i want to read the json in object format.

Here is my code in view

```
    <#import "../Shared/Master.ftl" as layout /> 
    <#assign TitleContent in layout>
    Home Page
    </#assign>  
    <#assign Recipient =  controller.ViewData.data> 
    ${Recipient}
```

In my controller.cs

```
    dynamic obj = JObject.Parse("{'contact':{ 'cx_outstandingamountid':{ 
    'cx_outstandingamount':'ytest' } } }"); 
    ViewData["data"] = obj; 
    return View();
```

Now the view is rendering as

```
    {'contact':{ 'cx_outstandingamountid':{'cx_outstandingamount':'ytest' } } }
```

But i want to render as 'ytest'. for this i tried

```
${Recipient.contact.cx_outstandingamountid.cx_outstandingamount}
```

but it did not work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What's the error message, or how exactly it didn't work?

Comment: @ddekany In view , json output is coming as string. i want that as object so that i can give like below ${Recipient.contact.cx_outstandingamountid.cx_outstandingamount}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to use eval to parse the json in freemarker. Refer [here](https://web.liferay.com/web/allen.ziegenfus/blog/-/blogs/working-with-json-in-freemarker).

```
<#assign recip=controller.ViewData.data>
<#assign Recipient = recip?eval>    
${Recipient.contact.acsi_outstandingamountid.acsi_outstandingamount}
```